# Почему в Golang defer используется после обработки ошибки, а не до?

Tags: golang

Например, я часто встречаю следующее использование:

```go
response, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer response.Body.Close()
```

но почему бы не сделать так?

```go
response, err := http.Get(url)
defer response.Body.Close()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

некоторые линтеры ругаются на подобное, хочу понять почему?

Comment: именно первый вариант приведен в документации. Возможно, оно само закрывает в случае ошибки и делать ничего не нужно

Answer (score 2):

Если во время `http.Get` вернулась ошибка, то `response` будет равен `nil`.
В таком случае:

1. `response.Body.Close()` вызовет панику, т.к. `response` это `nil` и у него нету `Body`
2. Если `response` это `nil`, то нет нужды закрывать `Body`, ибо он не создан даже.

Именно из-за этого линтер и ругается, т.к. будет там ошибка или нет станет понятно только при выполнении, но данный код в любом случае "ненадежный" (`may have nil or other unexpected value`)

Comment: хорошо, в этом примере ясно. спасибо

Comment: Обратите внимание, что response.Body.Close() возвращает ошибку, ее бы то же хорошо обрабатывать. И некоторые линтеры ругаются, что ошибка не обработана. При большом желании можно организовать возврат ошибки из defer в результат родительской функции